# Does free iWork iOS entitle older devices?

Tags: ios, iwork

I wonder whether old iOS devices would become entitled to install a free copy of iWork after purchasing a new device.

Comment: You get the iWork version for iOS7 for free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, providing you use the same Apple ID. When you purchase iWork for free on your new device, it is added to your purchases and then available to download on your other devices.